# Element Meta Image (OG/Twitter) Wiped On Save

Tags: plugin-sproutseo

I'm giving Sprout SEO a try specifically for the Facebook OG and Twitter card handling - however specifically in these two cases, when I choose an image, it gets wiped. No messages or errors.

I've tried both already uploaded images and newly uploaded images.

This is only the case when editing an Element, not a Section.

Anyone else had this issue?

Craft CMS 2.6.2903 | Sprout SEO 3.2.0

Comment: Hi James, could you please confirm if you're trying to add the images in a Section or Element field type? would you be able to add a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: Hey James, would be great if you can submit a support ticket here: https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/request/support

Comment: Hi Andre. It's for an element field type (section appears fine). I'll submit a support ticket.